# My regex is returning nil everytime in obj-c, example code included

Tags: ios, objective-c, regex, nsstring

**edit i clarified exactly what text im getting stored in a string.**

So heres my regex https://regex101.com/r/fWFRya/5 -this had the wrong string zz, thats why everyone was confused my mistake it is fixed now see again

```
^.*?".*?:\s+(?|(?:(.*?[!.?])\s+.*?)|(.*?))".*$
```

heres how it looks in my code, backslashes added to escape quotes

```
NSString *regexTweet = @"^.*?\".*?:\\s+(?|(?:(.*?[!.?])\\s+.*?)|(.*?))\".*$";
//the example string contains the text>   @user hey heres my message: first message: and a second colon! haha.
      NSString *example1 = @"@user hey heres my message: first message: and a second colon! haha.";
  NSError *regexerror = nil;
  NSRegularExpression *regex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:regexTweet options:NSRegularExpressionCaseInsensitive error:&regexerror];

  NSRange range = [regex rangeOfFirstMatchInString:example1
  options:0
  range:NSMakeRange(0, [example1 length])];
  NSString *final1 = [example1 substringWithRange:range];
  HBLogDebug (@"example 1 has become %@", final1);
```

when I log final1 it always returns nil and i'm unable to figure out where it's going wrong, I would appreciate if someone could give me a hand

**expected output is**

***first message: and a second colon!***

Comment: Change the example line to `NSString *example1 = @"\"@user hey heres my message: first message: and a second colon! haha.\"";` and it should work. Check your engine supports branch reset construct `(?|..)` If not, it's not really needed, and can be accomplished making it just a cluster group `^.*?".*?:\s+(?:(?:(.*?[!.?])\s+.*?)|(.*?))".*$` The answer is just a concatenation of `$1$2` since only one group can contain a string. This will keep intact the trimming you are now doing.

Comment: @sln i had the wrong string in that regex link (i forgot to change it when i fixed the one on here), can you check again please? sorry

Comment: Possibly you're having a mental block. The regex will only match a string that has 2 double quotes in it. To _make that a language string_ those quotes have to be escaped. `string var = " <- begin of string, quote 1 \" and quote 2 \" end of string ->";`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you created a regex for `NSString *example1 = @("@user hey heres my message: first message: and a second colon! haha");`, but the string you pass to the regex engine in the code is `@user hey heres my message: first message: and a second colon! haha`.

**I assume that you need to match a string like `Text.. "@user hey heres my message: first message: and a second colon! haha"`**.

Note that [ICU regex  library](http://www.icu-project.org/userguide/regexp) does not support [Branch Reset Groups](http://www.regular-expressions.info/branchreset.html).

I suggest changing the branch reset group into a *capturing group* with an alternation group:

```
^.*?:\s+(.*?[!.?](?=\s)|[^"]*).*$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/4X3isB/1)

**Details**:

- `^` - start of the string
- `.*?:` - any 0+ chars up to the first `:` that is followed with
- `\s+`  - 1 or more whitespaces...
- `(.*?[!.?](?=\s)|[^"]*)`  - Group 1 capturing either

  - `.*?[!.?](?=\s)` - any 0+ chars as few as possible up to the first `!`, `.` or `?` that are followed with whitespace
  - `|` - or
  - `[^"]*` - zero or more chars other than `"`
- `.*$`  - any 0+ chars up to the end of string

All you need is to access Group 1 to get the value you need. See a sample [Objective-C demo](https://ideone.com/7QLGvM).

Comment: I fixed the string, i have been logging too much & accidentally mixed them up while writing it in here.         have not been able to get your above suggestion working yet (likely because the assumption is not exactly what i was going for, which is my mistake for having written it wrong) would appreciate if you could take another look

Comment: Let me first make sure the input is correct. [Does it look like this?](https://regex101.com/r/4X3isB/1)